# Convert DataRowCollection to NameValueCollection

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, datarow, namevaluecollection

I need an elegant way to convert a DataRowCollection to a NameValueCollection.

note: during the conversion I need a section where I can invoke an inflector to tidy up key names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop over the rows and add the desired columns manually.

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
dt.Rows.Add(1, "Hello");
dt.Rows.Add(2, "World");
dt.Rows.Add(1, "Foo"); // dupe key

var nvc = new NameValueCollection();
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    string key = row[0].ToString();
    // tidy up key here
    nvc.Add(key, row[1].ToString());
}

// display nvc
foreach (var key in nvc.AllKeys)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", key, nvc[key]);
```

If you're interested in a `Dictionary` you could use `ToDictionary`, however this won't work if duplicate keys are allowed. In that case another elegant solution would be to use `ToLookup`.

```
// optionally use a Func to do the tidying up
// or call an existing method or do it inline for simple operations
Func<string, string> tidyFunc = (s) => s.Trim();
var lookup = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
               .ToLookup(r => tidyFunc(r[0].ToString()), r => r[1].ToString());

foreach (var g in lookup)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key: " + g.Key);
    foreach (var item in g)
        Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. could you enlighten me what does this do. I am not well versed with LINQ ToLookup(r => tidyFunc(r[0].ToString()), r => r[1].ToString())

Comment: @geocine first the `Cast<DataRow>()` is needed to get an `IEnumerable<DataRow>` in order to use LINQ extension methods on the result. Next, `ToLookup` is iterating over all the `DataRow` items and a key selector is specified via the lambda expression that takes the current row in the iteration and uses it to specify the key (the `r => r[0]...` part). Likewise an element selector is used to specify the data to extra (the `r => r[1]...` part). A lookup consists of key values and the elements that belong to a key, thus giving you a *1 to many* lookup structure. Hope that helps!

Comment: string key = row[0].ToString();
does not get the key but the value at row[0].. how would I suppose to get the key name.

Comment: @geocine if you want the column names use `dt.Columns[0].ColumnName` or loop through the `DataTable.Columns` property. If that's not what you're after please clarify what you mean by "key" and give an example of what the table looks like and what the expected output should be.